# is it possible to record calls in android 10+ devices?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, call-recording

not able to record calls in android 10+ phones

```
            recorder = MediaRecorder()
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            recorder.setOutputFile(path)
            recorder.prepare()
            recorder.start()
```

Comment: to let us better help you, you should more elaborate your question by adding for example the error you receive and more info

Comment: this fun calling when call started, the file is created with size, but sound muted